# Run a method upon NSWindow opening?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I have a NSWindow that I am launching `makeKeyAndOrderFront` to the window from a MenuBarItem in an .xib file - it works, great.

However, I want to run a method when this window opens, so I subclassed NSWindow and set the window to the subclass.

When I do the shortcut, the window opens but is not the main window, when doing `-(void)makeKeyWindow`

When I do `-(void)makeMainWindow`, the NSLog does nothing.

And, when I override `makeKeyAndOrderFront`, it doesn't show at all (as expected).

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What controller owns this window?  With an NSWindowController subclass, you could use `windowDidLoad`

Comment: @stevesliva, the window loading is not the same thing as the window showing.

Comment: The method is `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` with a colon, not just `-makeKeyAndOrderFront`. That's an important distinction. You may have failed to override the existing method and just created a new method that nobody ever calls. By the way, since you're calling `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` to show the window, why do you need to be called to know when it's shown? The code which calls `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` already knows.

Comment: @KenThomases Sorry, yes, I am using it with a colon.  I call makeKeyAndOrderFront from Interface Builder.  However, I want to run a method when that window is shown, so when I implement that method in my NSWindow subclass, I get an NSLog(), but the window itself is not shown...

Comment: I guess you're not calling through to `super`.

Comment: @KenThomases how do you mean?

Comment: @KenThomases Never mind, thanks!  Should have thought of that... If you answer, I'll check it!

Comment: the first place I would look would be the delegate to see what kind of callbacks are available, and which is most appropriate for you needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the window stopped showing up when you overrode `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:` is that you neglected to make your override call through to `super`'s implementation.

[Edit by Asker]

To add code, here's what it should be:

```
- (void)makeKeyAndOrderFront:(id)sender {
    // what to do when the window is shown:

    [super makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender]; // key line, you MUST have this
}
```